# How do I show three unit circles next to each other is homotopy equivalent to. bouquet of three circles?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, circles, homotopy-theory, retraction

I am studying a topology text, and got stuck on a problem.

Let $X$ be a union of three unit circles centered at $(-2, 0)$, $(0, 0)$ and $(2, 0)$. How do I show that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of three circles?

The book gives a hint to consider another problem that allows me to move three points, and I think it might be possible to say that both spaces are deformation contract of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{x, y, z \}$ for some $\{x, y, z \} \subset \mathbb R^2$, but not sure how rigorously argue it.

Can someone please correct me if I am wrong, and provide a detailed solution? The textbook lacks examples showing spaces are homotopy equivalent, and I am planning to do other problems that ask me to find homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Hint: you might be able to come up with an argument using deformation retractions, but I think it easier just to design an explicit homotopy equivalence that shrinks one semicircle of the middle circle to a point.

Comment: Could you give me more? I don't have a clear idea about how to design any homotopy equivalence now.

Comment: I should have said that the inverse mapping from the bouquet to the line of circles works by flattening part of one of the circles onto a line segment like a balloon on a string. You can then identify the other two circles with two adjacent circles and use the string to get round the middle circle so you can map what's left of the partly flattened circle onto the third circle in the line.